# NodeJS changes not reflected on server

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm running NodeJS application on CentOS with PM2. Everything works fine.

But I made a query changes in one of the controller file (add new column in SQL query). And then uploaded the project files to server. And then run PM2 restart [app-id].

It's strange that new column was not returned in the api response payload.

Is there anyway to clear cache of PM2? or What is the issue exactly?

Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

For me worked `sudo -u nodejs pm2 restart hello`

more info:
https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/nodejs#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command.

```
pm2 stop app_name
pm2 restart app_name
pm2 reload app_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind advise! I just tried three of above commands you listed. But changes still not reflected yet.